# Quotient Group question about order of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

How do I prove that when an element of $G/K$ (where $K$ is normal subgroup of $G$) has an order $n$, there exists an element in $G$ having order $n$?
I could only do as the order of elements are $n$. The total number of elements in $G$ are $nm$. How to proceed?

Comment: It's not true, take $G = \mathbb{Z}$ and $K = (5)$. Maybe you misread the problem?

Comment: @LorenzoNajt In your example the order of $G$ is infinite while the questioner specifies the order of $|G|=mn$ is finite.

Comment: Say that $gK$ has order $n$ in $G/K$. What do you know about the order of $g$ in $G$?

Answer (score 1):

Let the element of $G/K$ of order $n$ be say $rK$. $(rK)^{|r|} = K$, so $n$ divides $|r|$, say $|r| = nk$. Then consider $r^k$. Clearly $|r^k| =n$.

(Edit: Showing $|r^k|=n$: Suppose by way of contradiction $|r^k|\neq n$. Then $|r^k|$ is, say, $l$, and we know $l$ divides $n$. Hence $l<n$. Then $(r^k)^l=1$ so $|r|\leq lk<nk$, a contradiction).

Comment: $r^{kn}=1$ doesn't imply that $r^k$ has order $n$, just that it has order *dividing* $n$.

Comment: @RobertShore. Thank you for commenting. It does in this case, because $|r|=nk$. Suppose $|r^k|\neq  n.$ Then because, as you said, $|r^k|$ has order dividing $n$, $|r^k|=l<n$ implies $r^{lk} = 1$. Since $lk<kn = |r|$ we have a contradiction.

Comment: @CMoore May I suggest that you edit your answer to include this comment?

Comment: @RobertShore Good idea, just changed it

Comment: As far as the edit concerns, we could also note that $|r^k|=\frac{|r|}{{\rm{gcd}}(k,|r|)}=\frac{nk}{{\rm{gcd}}(k,nk)}=\frac{nk}{k}=n$.